# Using sorted on list of dictionaries multiple times on different keys - is order preservation guaranteed?

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

Say you have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
x = [{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3},{"a":3,"b":2,"c":4},{"a":2,"b":1,"c":4},{"a":1,"b":3,"c":1}]
```

And you want to sort by priority of `a`, then `b`, then `c`, so logically you sort the other way round:

```
x = sorted(x, key = lambda x: x["c"])
x = sorted(x, key = lambda x: x["b"])
x = sorted(x, key = lambda x: x["a"])
```

Within the items in the last sort of the same value (either after the sort by `b` or by `a`), is the order of the items from the last sort **guaranteed**? I have tested it and it seems to be the case, but I would like to see this verified to put my mind at rest.

Comment: could you be more clear?. if you want to sort by three values `x = sorted(x, key = lambda x: (x["a"],x["b"],x["c"]))` this should work.

Comment: @The6thSense or use `itemgetter('a', 'b', 'c')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation of the `list` type says:

> The `sort()` method is guaranteed to be stable. A sort is stable if it
>   guarantees not to change the relative order of elements that compare
>   equal — this is helpful for sorting in multiple passes (for example,
>   sort by department, then by salary grade).